# evdev can't distinguish certain keys on Tivo Slide Pro

Tags: evdev

I have a Tivo Slide Pro RF remote with its USB receiver connected to an Ubuntu 14.04 system. It works in HID mode and looks like a keyboard.

Most keys work fine through evdev, but there's four keys that all send the same evdev events, and I can't find any way to distinguish among these four keys. Running evtest shows the following events when I press & release any one of these four keys:

```
Event: time 1415581661.700911, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 40 (ABS_MISC), value 0
Event: time 1415581661.700911, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1415581662.028970, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 40 (ABS_MISC), value 1
Event: time 1415581662.028970, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

The USB key is designed to be plugged into a TiVo, which obviously has some way to distinguish. Where do I start tracking this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the special TiVo Slide driver was not being used for this new model of remote because the USB ID was not updated in the driver source. Specifically this line from hid-ids.h should read:

```
#define USB_DEVICE_ID_TIVO_SLIDE        0x1203
```

(While that works for the new TiVo Slide Pro, it breaks the older TiVo Slide.)